# Sequel making the following one query running an exclude from a join table

Tags: ruby, sequel

I have a `users` table and a `blocked_users` table. `users` has all my authentication data, site preferences, etc, and `blocked_users` has a `source_id` and a `target_id`.

I would like to return a collection of all users that a user has not blocked and that have not blocked the current user.

Right now I have the following code which I execute by calling `@user.available_users` but it executes three queries. Is there some way to make this a single query?

```
class User < Sequel::Model

  one_to_many :blocked_users,     :key=>:source_id
  one_to_many :blocked_by_users,  :key=>:target_id, :class => BlockedUser

  def block_user(id)
    BlockedUser.create({source_id:self.id, target_id:id})
  end 

  def blocked_user_ids
    self.blocked_users.map{|bu| bu[:target_id]}
  end 

  def blocked_by_user_ids
    self.blocked_by_users.map{|bu| bu[:target_id]}
  end 

  def available_users
    User.exclude(:id=>self.blocked_users.map{|bu| bu[:target_id]}).exclude(:id=>self.blocked_by_users.map{|bu| bu[:target_id]})
  end 
end
```

I added the following method to my User class:

```
  def test_avail
    User.exclude(:blocked_users=>self).exclude(:blocked_by_users=>self)
  end 

1.9.3p0 :001 > User.all.first.test_avail
   INFO - (0.000732s) SELECT * FROM `users`
Sequel::Error: invalid association class User for association :blocked_users used in dataset filter for model User, expected class BlockedUser
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using filter by associations support is probably easiest:

```
def available_users
  User.exclude(:blocked_users=>self).exclude(:blocked_by_users=>self)
end
```

Comment: Hey so I added the changes in the above question but now with that snippet I get 
   Sequel::Error: invalid association class User for association        :blocked_users used in dataset filter for model User, expected class BlockedUser

Comment: My bad.  The code would work if blocked_users and blocked_by_users were self referential many_to_many associations.  Instead, you are using a separate BlockedUser class and one_to_many associations.  I'm not sure why you set it up that way.  With your current code, you should be able to do User.exclude(:id=>self.blocked_users_dataset.select(:target_id)).